# jQuery Datatables - footerCallback sum columns, issues with table total

Tags: datatables

ive created a function that I can call on columns that I wish to sum up using the below. however the total (table total) entry for column 9 is always zero. the page total seems to work. and the page total and table total for column 9 works also.

```
"footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
            var api = this.api(), data;
            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
            var intVal = function ( i ) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\£,]/g, '')*1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
            };
            var column_sum = function (col) {
                // Total over all pages
                total = api
                    .column(col)
                    .data()
                    .reduce( function (a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    }, 0 );
                // Total over this page
                pageTotal = api
                    .column(col, { page: 'current'} )
                    .data()
                    .reduce( function (a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    }, 0 );
                return accounting.formatMoney(pageTotal) +' ('+ accounting.formatMoney(total) +' total)'
            };
            // Update footer
            $( api.column(6).footer()).html(
                column_sum(6)
            );
            $( api.column(9).footer()).html(
                column_sum(9)
            );
        }
```

**EDIT**

I have added some sanitised data. currently the page total works for the first column and second columns.

The all pages total does not work. i.e each time I filter by the column header I should see the total across each page

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" id="circuit_list"
 role="grid" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Info</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Cost PM</th>
            <th>Term</th>
            <th>Remaining Term</th>
            <th>Remaining Cost</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/circuits/edit/238/1/all_cl" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">
                    <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>Fibre</td>
            <td>£950.00</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>£0.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/circuits/edit/238/2/all_cl" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">
                    <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>Fibre</td>
            <td>£950.00</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>£0.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/circuits/edit/333/101/all_cl" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">
                    <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>MPLS</td>
            <td>£1791.33</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>£19,704.63</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/circuits/edit/334/101/all_cl" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">
                    <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>MPLS</td>
            <td>£100.00</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>£1,100.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/circuits/edit/235/1/all_cl" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">
                    <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>MPLS</td>
            <td>£593.33</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>£8,899.95</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/circuits/edit/317/82/all_cl" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">
                    <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>Fibre</td>
            <td>£103.00</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>£0.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/circuits/edit/229/2/all_cl" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">
                    <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>MPLS</td>
            <td>£373.33</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>£4,106.63</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/circuits/edit/233/1/all_cl" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">
                    <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>DSL</td>
            <td>£1837.66</td>
            <td>60</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>£11,025.96</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/circuits/edit/234/1/all_cl" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">
                    <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>DSL</td>
            <td>£373.34</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>£5,600.10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/circuits/edit/243/5/all_cl" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">
                    <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>DSL</td>
            <td>£373.34</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>£5,600.10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/circuits/edit/244/4/all_cl" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">
                    <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>MPLS</td>
            <td>£373.34</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>£4,480.08</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/circuits/edit/324/83/all_cl" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">
                    <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>4G</td>
            <td>£103.00</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>£0.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/circuits/edit/2/6/all_cl" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">
                    <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>4G</td>
            <td>£41.50</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/circuits/edit/57/18/all_cl" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">
                    <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>4G</td>
            <td>£45.00</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>£0.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/circuits/edit/113/35/all_cl" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">
                    <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>Fibre</td>
            <td>£45.00</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>£0.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/circuits/edit/218/71/all_cl" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">
                    <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>4G</td>
            <td>£57.00</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>£0.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/circuits/edit/264/71/all_cl" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">
                    <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>MPLS</td>
            <td>£45.00</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>£0.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/circuits/edit/269/61/all_cl" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">
                    <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>DSL</td>
            <td>£45.00</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>£0.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/circuits/edit/300/85/all_cl" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">
                    <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>4G</td>
            <td>£30.00</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/circuits/edit/307/76/all_cl" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">
                    <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>4G</td>
            <td>£45.00</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>270.00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of the column data? Also, does the table total for col 9 work or not? You write: "_the total (table total) entry for column 9 is always zero_" and "_and the page total and table total for column 9 works also._" So which is it?

Comment: Can you post a plunker or fiddle that shows your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most probably in one or more of the cells for column 9, the value there fails to convert to a number and you are getting a **NaN** returned by **intVal** function.

There are 2 issues in **intVal**:

1. line `i.replace(/[\£,]/g, '')*1` can return **NaN**
2. `typeof i === 'number'` can be true for **NaN**

From what it seems, intVal is trying to check for this, but the logic is wrong.
change the **intVal** to:

```
var intVal = function ( i ) {

   if(typeof i === 'string') {
         i = i.replace(/[\£,]/g, '')*1;
   }
   // check if you got a valid number.
   if (Number.isNaN(i)) {
         return 0;
   }
   return i;
};
```

If the **filtered total** is needed, use:

```
total = api.column(col, {"filter": "applied"})
```

or

```
total = api.column(col, {"search": "applied"})
```

Comment: @AlexW Can you try the intVal above?

Comment: the single page totals work, however the the multi page totals do not. I have 10 entires per page, but if there is 20 entires in the filtered search it should show the total for all 20 entires. if it is unfiltered it should show the totals for everything

Comment: I think the "intVal" you got from the datatables example is not error resistent. Try the intVal in my answer, I tested with your data and it worked.

Comment: I get the same thing, the current page totals work, but the filtered totals do not, they always say the same sample here "£1,175.01 (£37,862.62 total) £15,600.15 (££1,233.49 total)" not sure why the second Total has the double £ sign in either?

Comment: Try: total = api.column(col, {"filter": "applied"})   or  total = api.column(col, {"search": "applied"})      if I understand correcly you want the filtered total.

Comment: where would I put that filtered total in the function?

Comment: var column_sum = function (col) { // Total over all pages total = api .column(col, {"filter": "applied"}) .data() .reduce( function (a, b) { return intVal(a) + intVal(b); }, 0 );  change it like this, hope it helps.

Comment: that didn't seem to work, the totals are set to zero

Comment: Tested with the sample data & the 2 above modifications and it seems to work. Can you try removing "accounting.formatMoney" from your totals?